# Pinescript - How to pass current date in timestamp?

Tags: pine-script

how to get timestamp of the current date?
yearCTD, monthCTD and dateCTD all returns as series but timestamp accepts only integer.

basically trying to anchor vwap for each day automatically instead of changing dates manually.

Thanks

```
src = hlc3

YearCTD = year(timenow)
monthCTD = month(timenow)
dateCTD = dayofmonth(timenow)

momentCTD = timestamp(YearCTD, monthCTD, dateCTD, 9, 30) <= error due to series

startCTD = time >= momentCTD and time[1] < momentCTD

sumSrcCTD = src * volume
sumVolCTD = volume
sumSrcCTD := startCTD ? sumSrcCTD : sumSrcCTD + sumSrcCTD[1]
sumVolCTD := startCTD ? sumVolCTD : sumVolCTD + sumVolCTD[1]

plot(sumSrcCTD / sumVolCTD, title="CTD_VWAP", color=blue)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use v4:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
src = hlc3

YearCTD = year(timenow)
monthCTD = month(timenow)
dateCTD = dayofmonth(timenow)

momentCTD = timestamp(YearCTD, monthCTD, dateCTD, 9, 30)

startCTD = time >= momentCTD and time[1] < momentCTD

sumSrcCTD = src * volume
sumVolCTD = volume
sumSrcCTD := startCTD ? sumSrcCTD : sumSrcCTD + sumSrcCTD[1]
sumVolCTD := startCTD ? sumVolCTD : sumVolCTD + sumVolCTD[1]

plot(sumSrcCTD / sumVolCTD, title="CTD_VWAP", color=color.blue)
```

[image]