# How to get timestamp in Pine script?

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to get timestamp of 52 week high in the format : timestamp(year, month, day) to be used programatically for further plots

I want to use the 52 week high / low to feed in the following code for anchored vwap.

+++

```
src = input(hlc3)
year = input(2021)
month = input(2)
day = input(16)

moment = timestamp(year, month, day)
start = time >= moment and time[1] < moment

sumSrc = src * volume
sumVol = volume
sumSrc := start ? sumSrc : sumSrc + sumSrc[1] 
sumVol := start ? sumVol : sumVol + sumVol[1]

plot(sumSrc / sumVol, title="VWAP", color=color.red)
```

+++

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pinescript - How to pass current date in timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61502345/pinescript-how-to-pass-current-date-in-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ta.highest()` to get the highest value, and `ta.highestbars()` to get the offset of the highest value in the given range. Note that `ta.highestbars()` returns a negative offset, so you need to invert the sign.

Then you can call `dayofmonth`, `month`, `year` functions to get the time information at a specific index.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
len = 52
hi = ta.highest(len)
hiOffset = - ta.highestbars(len)
hiDay = dayofmonth(time[hiOffset])
hiMonth = month(time[hiOffset])
hiYear = year(time[hiOffset])
plot(series=hi, color=color.blue)
plot(series=hiDay, color=color.green)
plot(series=hiMonth, color=color.orange)
plot(series=hiYear, color=color.red)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to obtain the VWAP anchored to the highest high / lowest low of a rolling 52 week window, then there isn't an ideal way to do this in pine. We can get close by using `timenow` and subtracting 52 weeks in milliseconds, but `timenow`'s value is determined when the script is loaded, which means to obtain a current accurate initialization the script **must be reloaded** each time you want to ensure the result is accurate.

Pine's execution model excludes being able to reference future data, even when the script is executing on an historical bar. So we have no way to determine the highest high or lowest low until we reach the most recent bar. But at that point in execution, it is too late to begin calculating and plotting the VWAP.

We can work around this by obtaining the start time using `timenow`, and from that point, each time a new higher high / lower low is found, begin calculating a new VWAP.

```
//@version=5
indicator("52 week H/L VWAP", overlay = true)

ts = timenow - 31449600000

start = time >= ts and time[1] < ts
active = time > ts and time[1] > ts

var float hpvsum = na
var float hvsum = na

var float lpvsum = na
var float lvsum = na

var float highest_high = na
var float lowest_low = na


if start
    highest_high := high
    lowest_low := low
else if active
    highest_high := math.max(highest_high, high)
    lowest_low := math.min(lowest_low, low)
    
if ta.change(highest_high) != 0
    hpvsum := hlc3 * volume
    hvsum := volume
else if active
    hpvsum += hlc3 * volume
    hvsum += volume

if ta.change(lowest_low) != 0
    lpvsum := hlc3 * volume
    lvsum := volume
else if active
    lpvsum += hlc3 * volume
    lvsum += volume


hvwap = hpvsum / hvsum
lvwap = lpvsum / lvsum

plot(hvwap, color = color.lime)
plot(lvwap, color = color.red)
```